# Can't access folders with special characters on mounted windows cifs share

Tags: debian, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, cifs

I've got an issue on a Debian(11.3) server we host, I mounted a windows server share through cifs and fstab but when I try to access or list a few folders which contains special characters like "[](https://unicode.bayashi.net/0xF028/%EF%80%A8)" I have an error saying that the folder doesn't exist. Here is the mount arguments :

```
auto,user=,pass=,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm
```

I tried to change to cp850 and a few others, nothing changes.
Here is the locale output :

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Interesting fact, if i try to create a local folder on ext4 partition with the special character listed above it works and i can list it.

If I could settled with just renaming folders i would do it but there's 100% chance that the client will receive other folders like that regurlarly.

Thank in advance for any hint or help, I made quite a few searches and don't find solutions

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn’t use utf-8 for file name encoding.
Thus, you cannot see window’s non-ascii folders and files properly from linux.
You can change window’s default encoding to utf-8 but I’m not sure whether this option is available or not for Windows 2012R2.
Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window) (`intl.cpl` method).

Comment: `chcp` only sets the encoding Windows uses on the _console_, it doesn't affect the filesystem.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for comment. I modified answer a bit for details.

Comment: Thank you for the answers i'll look into that